# What unicode it is to make such an effect? =͟͟͞͞s=͟͟͞͞s=͟͟͞͞s=͟͟͞͞s=͟͟͞͞s=͟͟͞͞s=͟͟͞͞s=͟͟͞͞s

Tags: fonts, font-size

It seems like its overlapping with the next characters, is there any specific category of this kind of chars? I just found some examples, like =͟͟͞͞  , 焰ྂ,冰҈

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are called combining characters. The [Wikipedia page is helpful](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combining_character).

The overline is called [COMBINING DOUBLE MACRON](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/35e/index.htm)
The underline is called [COMBINING DOUBLE MACRON BELOW](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/35f/index.htm).